# Does Volt(Phalcon) has something like request.ajax extends like Twig?

Tags: twig, template-engine, phalcon, volt

I would like to detect on Volt view, if is using ajax the request, extends from other template, is this possible?

```
{% extends request.ajax ? "base_ajax.html" : "base.html" %}
```

Thank's for help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Closer solution is using partials, is gonna change the logic for rendering views but is the only way to make it...

```
{{ request.isAjax()?partial("base/base-ajax") :partial("base/base-default") }}
```

Thank's for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything that is inside your [**DI container**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html) is available to use inside Volt templates ([**source**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#inject-services-into-a-template)). The [**request service**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/request.html) is by default in your DI and can be used in Volt as well:

```
{% set baseFile = request.isAjax() ? "base_ajax.volt" : "base.volt" %}
{% extends baseFile %}
```

You can check [**this list**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#service-name-conventions) to see all services that are available by default in the DI container.

Comment: Thanks @cvsguimaraes for help, but this cause error: "...**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Exception' with message 'Syntax error, unexpected token IDENTIFIER(request) in**...", the only way that could work is doing this: 
{% if request.isAjax() %}..... {% else %}....

Comment: Thank's for help..!, but "...Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Exception' with message 'Syntax error, unexpected token IDENTIFIER(baseFile) in...", Im gonna use this way:  ({% if request.isAjax() %}..... {% else %}....) , hope that volt add this facility in next updates.... thank's!

Comment: @user2976753 Yeah, it seems that `extends` doesn't support string variables.